# How to order table view with numbers 1-2-3

Tags: javafx, tableview, fxml, scenebuilder

I have a table view , and I want to order my rows

for example first row take 1 , the second take 2

I have tried to use

```
protected static ObservableList<Employee> data = FXCollections.<Employee>observableArrayList();
int i = data.size() + 1;
```

in my column

But when I delete row , 
and add new row I got bug in order

for example : I have 2 rows , I have delete the first row,
                 and add new row it should take different order
                 but I got same number.

I hope you understand my language .

Comment: *"The ordering is wrong"* is not a sufficient description of the problem. What would be the expected result? What result do you get instead? What code is used to replace the row? Where is the number stored? ect. ect...

Comment: Maybe you're confusing between `add `and `set`, the 1st adds a new (element/index), and the 2nd replaces an existing one, Another thing the elements in an `ObservableList `follow an order by creation, so no need to order them, if you want to use an element you call it by its index (the index begins with 0)

Answer (score 0):

You can call `myTableView.sort();` after you added or removed rows. Of course you have to define the sort order first, with a statement like this: `myTableView.getSortOrder().add(myColumn);`

Comment: you mean the sort order? when you initiate your table.